# linux ip routing problem juju lxd

Tags: networking, server, juju, ethernet, lxd

i want to juju bootstrap localhost

but the client cannot connect to the lxd daemon during installation..it seems to be a routing problem. both subnets are on the same vlan.

`baum@maas:~/.local/share/juju$ juju bootstrap conjure localhost --bootstrap-series=xenial --config no-proxy=10.14.162.1 --config apt-http-proxy=http://192.168.10.253:3128 --config apt-https-proxy=http://192.168.10.253:3128 --config http-proxy=http://192.168.10.253:3128 --config https-proxy=http://192.168.10.253:3128`

vlan 400

192.168.10.0/24

10.14.162.0/24

please take a look at

http://paste.ubuntu.com/21993165/

Answer (score 0):

You got a lot going on there. Honestly no clue what juju is or how you bootstrap localhost with it, or why you have different subnets that are on the same VLAN? Which looks like is your problem here. Try to break down big problem to the basic components which are failing. Looks like you're trying to ping your lxdbr0 interface (10.14.162.1) from your ens160 (192.168.10.1) which are both on the same ethernet segment. So the router just responds with hey dummy the 10.14.162.1 is right here on the same segment so you can address it directly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Redirect